# How I can upgrade an new version of container in Openshift/Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift, openshift-origin

I have an openshift cluster.
Docker images I store in a gitlab registry
And I have a question, when I have a new image on my repo, how can I upgrade an my application in openshift?

for example I have a deployed selenium hub with version 3.6 :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose-debug.yml
    kompose.version: 1.6.0 (e4adfef)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: ds-hub
  name: ds-hub
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: ds-hub
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: GRID_CLEAN_UP_CYCLE
          value: "10000"
        - name: GRID_MAX_SESSION
          value: "10"
        - name: GRID_TIMEOUT
          value: "150"
        image: selenium/hub:3.6
        name: ds-hub
        ports:
        - containerPort: 4444
        resources: {}
        stdin: true
        tty: true
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

and now I want to deploy a new version for example 3.7

The only way I know, to do it - is to change in yaml file:

from

```
image: selenium/hub:3.6
```

to

```
image: selenium/hub:3.7
```

and in console replace yaml file with new version:

```
oc replace -f <yml_file_describing_pod>
```

Maybe is it a better solution to do this? Or maybe pod can upgrade automatically? And how I can do this from web?

Comment: I suppose you're familiar with https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/deployments/basic_deployment_operations.html right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an automatic update, you can add an ImageChange-trigger to your Deployment-Config and use selenium/hub:latest as ImageStreamTag-name.

```
    triggers:
  - type: ImageChange
    imageChangeParams:
      automatic: true 
      from:
        kind: ImageStreamTag
        name: selenium/hub:latest
      containerNames:
        - ds-hub
```

Comment: Could make sense to have a own tag for different deployments (e.g. testing, staging, prod,...) instead of using latest.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to your k8s cluster via kubectl? If yes, you can set the new image for your deployment and perform a rolling update:

```
kubectl set image deployment/ds-hub ds-hub=selenium/hub:3.7
```